# error: no matching function for call to ‘to_string(std::basic_string<char>&)’

Tags: c++, string, c++11, compiler-errors

Even though in a template I can have any type, the function `to_string` does not work on basic strings:

for example:

```
std::string str("my string");
my_class(str);
```

with this functor definition:

```
template<class valuetype>
void operator()(valuetype value)
{
    ...
    private_string_field = std::to_string(value);
```

does not work. here is the error:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘to_string(std::basic_string&)’

What is the best way to avoid it.

In advance, I request avoid linking to irrelevant questions just because of a few common keywords.

Comment: I am not going to go into whether it makes sense to not have `to_string` overloaded for `std::string`, but... why are you using it in the code above? The `operator<<` can take care of printing anything for which `to_string` is defined with a lower cost (no need to go through an intermediate `std::string`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas you are right. I just wanted to shorten the code so I put a `cout`. In fact, i need to store it somewhere and print it for later. inside a log file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) only works on fundamental numeric types.

If you need a more generic function, [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) will  work on many more types - effectively any type that can be sent to an `iostream`.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

...

private_string_field = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for basic string. It would have nothing to do.

After [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley)'s suggestion I would consider the following design, use `to_string` but provide default template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct Type {
  explicit operator std::string() const{
    return std::string("I am type");
  }
};

namespace std {
template <typename T>
  string to_string(const T& value) {
    return string(value);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // this is what would be in class
    Type x;
    std::string private_string_field;
    private_string_field = std::to_string(42);
    std::cout << private_string_field << std::endl;

    private_string_field = std::to_string(x);
    std::cout << private_string_field << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

By default it tries to cast the operand to a string. This way custom types can provide their own conversion. Alternative design would be to internally use `stringstream` and `operator<<` for conversions, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Type {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Type& value){
    return out << "Type through operator<<";
  }
};

template <class T>
std::string to_str(const T& value) {
  std::string ret;
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << value;
  ret = ss.str();
  return ret;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // this is what would be in class
    Type x;
    std::string private_string_field;
    private_string_field = to_str(42);
    std::cout << private_string_field << std::endl;

    private_string_field = to_str(x);
    std::cout << private_string_field << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was a good analysis until the code in the question got drastically changed.  :|

Comment: Now it handles strings correctly, but not much else.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Could you please elaborate? Something else needs to be "castable" to `std::string`. Or you mean that for example `int` won't work? Well an alternative would be to write a template overload for `to_string` that would try to cast to `string` it by default. Not sure if it's a better design.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It won't handle `int` or `double` or any of the other types for which there are `std::to_string`.overloads.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I updated my answer. Not sure if it's better than Drew's  (probably not) but at least it works for the cases you mentioned. Thanks for pointing it out.